# Mongodb aggregation issue

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a following data

data:

```js
[ 
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'bbb' },
    days: 120 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'ccc' },
    days: 120 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'aaa' },
    days: 158 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'aaa' },
    days: 161 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'aaa' },
    days: 162 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'aaa' },
    days: 163 },
  { _id:
     { year: 2014,
       distinct_id: 'ccc' },
    days: 169 } ]
```

I have a margin value of 160. I wanna do

1) filter the data with days less than the margin value of 160(**{days: {$lt: 160}}**) after run this pipeline, the result will be:

```js
[ 
      { _id:
         { year: 2014,
           distinct_id: 'bbb' },
        days: 120 },
      { _id:
         { year: 2014,
           distinct_id: 'ccc' },
        days: 120 },
      { _id:
         { year: 2014,
           distinct_id: 'aaa' },
        days: 158 }
]
```

2) since the **filter out data** are 'aaa', 'bbb' with **days values greater than 160**, the next pipeline with only keep data are not in the previous filter out data, so the result will be only:

```js
[ 
      { _id:
         { year: 2014,
           distinct_id: 'bbb' },
        days: 120 }
]
```

I do not know how to do the second pipeline to get only distinct_id 'bbb' after using the first result. please help

my aggregation is:

```js
[
    {
        $match: {
            'days': {
                $lt: 160
            }
        }
    },
    ????  what is next?
]
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing your actual question. Is their current code that you are trying but do not know what to do next? Part of that means is there an actual pipeline you are executing that gets you to your "input data" stage or are you even just asking how to filter your collection? You could edit/include code to make this clear.

Comment: i just revise a bit. my question is after filter the data with the margin value of 160. how can write the second pipeline to return the result with only distinct_id of 'bbb'.

Comment: Post your code. It seems like you can likely do this with one step. But we need your code to tell.

Comment: Just add my code, it is really simple just filter out the value greater than 160. and I do not know what is the next to get the desire value that the distinct_id is not in the filter out entry(aaa, ccc), which return me 'bbb' only, thanks

Comment: Is that your **only** code? If so then not really an aggregate question. At least it doesn't look like one. But the question is still very unclear. You need to explain what you mean by terms like "get only distinct_id 'bbb'". This looks really like all you want to do is match on both `{ "days": { "$lt": 160 }, "distinct_id": "bbb" }` If that is your entire operation then just use `find()`. Otherwise explain yourself as to why this does not get your result.